# Refer to text field by class instance name

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I need to populate the text field `tField` (defined on stage) that resides inside `ParentClass` (MovieClip with same class name). I want to be able to set `tField.text` to whatever I want from `AnotherClass`. How do I do it?

Comment: Does AnotherClass has a reference of ParentClass which contains the tField that you want to change?

Comment: Are you developing on the timeline?

Comment: taskinoor, AnotherClass has this "private var _anotherClass:AnotherClass;"

Comment: citizen conn, no it is not in timeline

Comment: You are trying to access tField of ParentClass, so you will need a reference to target ParentClass.

Comment: You better post the related codes.

Comment: Code is all over the place, not sure if it will help much, that's why I was trying to abstract the problem as much as possible

Comment: Without these we can't help. Is tField public/private? Do you have the reference in AnotherClass?

Comment: tField is just a name assigned to the text field it is not defined anywhere in the code

Answer (score 0):

Changed answer to full instructions because the asker is probably missing a key step through the Flash GUI.

1. Open Adobe Flash CS5 (might work for CS4 too.)
2. File, New, Actionscript 3.0.
3. Click the text tool. Draw a TextField.
4. Click the TextField, in the Properties window select Input Text in the drop down.
5. With the TextField still selected, in the Properties window, set the Instance Name to "tField" no quotes.
6. Click on the stage. In the Properties window set the Class: text field to "Main" no quotes.
7. File, Save As, "Test.fla" no quotes.
8. File, New, Actionscript 3.0 class.
9. Paste the following in to the new AS file:

   package
   {

   ```
   import flash.display.MovieClip;
   import flash.events.FullScreenEvent;
   import flash.events.MouseEvent;
   import flash.events.Event;

   public class Main extends MovieClip 
   {
       public function Main()
       {
           var another:Another = new Another(this.tField);
       }
   }
   ```

   }
10. File, Save As, "Main.as" no quotes, IN THE SAME DIRECTORY AS STEP 3.
11. File, New, Actionscript 3.0 class.
12. Paste the following code into the new .as file (I can't get StackOverflow to display this correctly. Just paste it as is):

    package
    {
        import flash.text.TextField;
        public class Another
        {
            public function Another(textField:TextField)
            {
                textField.text = "Hello";
            }
        }
    }
13. File, Save As, "Another.as" no quotes, in the SAME DIRECTORY AS STEP 3.
14. Hit Ctrl-Enter.

All drawing a TextField on the stage and setting its instance name does is secretly add the lines of code:

```
public var tField:TextField = new TextField();
tField.type = "input";
```

To whatever class the stage is associated with (in this case, the class Main.) If you need any more help than that, I would recommend getting a good book on AS3 programming and the Flash IDE because the answer is well beyond the scope of a simple StackOverflow answer.

Comment: I am trying this out and I get "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." :(

Answer (score 0):

Use [getChildByName](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName%28%29). First you create the `TextField` in a class.

```
import flash.display.TextField;

var tField:TextField = new TextField();
tField.name = "tField";

stage.addChild(tField);
```

Note that you need to set the name. In another class, you can use:

```
var tField:TextField = stage.getChildByName("tField");
trace(tField.name); // tField
```

Comment: How do I refer to the textfield that is inside the movie clip (added manually, not via as3)? MovieClip is placed on stage via as3.

Comment: If the MovieClip has a name, you can also use getChildByName.

Comment: Does that mean I can do something like this: stage.getChildByName("ParentClass").getChildByName("tField").text = "hi" ?

Comment: stage.getChildByName("ParentClass") will fail. The MovieClip that is automatically added to the stage is not named "ParentClass". The main movieclip on the stage is automatically named "root1". So, you'd actually have to do: TextField(MovieClip(this.stage.getChildByName("root1")).getChildByName("tField")).text = "bye"; However, I don't recommend relying on the name root1. See my full answer to more reliably hook code into the main movieclip.